# OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array')

Tags: c++, c, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project that uses opencv on raspberry pi. I have run into a hurdle which looks simple, but I am unable to solve the issue. 
First of all, here a part of my code:

```
    {
        gray=cvarrToMat(py);
        ///cvShowImage("camcvWin", py); // display only gray channel
        if(img_num%2 == 1)
        {
            cv::imwrite("/home/pi/test/Gray_2Image1.jpg",gray);
        }
        else if (img_num%2 == 0)
        {
            cv::imwrite( "/home/pi/test/Gray_2Image2.jpg", gray );  
            cv::Mat img2 = cv::imread("/home/pi/test/Gray_2Image2.jpg", 0);
            cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread("/home/pi/test/Gray_2Image1.jpg", 0);
            diffImage = abs(img1-img2);
            imshow("diffImage", diffImage);
            cv::imwrite( "/home/pi/test/Diffimage.jpg", diffImage );

        }          
        img_num++;
```

This code has no problem.
However, if I edit the code to make a slight modification as follows:

```
    {
        gray=cvarrToMat(py);
        ///cvShowImage("camcvWin", py); // display only gray channel
        if(img_num%2 == 1)
        {
            cv::imwrite("/home/pi/test/Gray_2Image1.jpg",gray);
            cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread("/home/pi/test/Gray_2Image1.jpg", 0);
        }
        else if (img_num%2 == 0)
        {
            cv::imwrite( "/home/pi/test/Gray_2Image2.jpg", gray );  
            cv::Mat img2 = cv::imread("/home/pi/test/Gray_2Image2.jpg", 0);
            diffImage = abs(img1-img2);
            imshow("diffImage", diffImage);
            cv::imwrite( "/home/pi/test/Diffimage.jpg", diffImage );

        }          
        img_num++;
```

I get the following error:

OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in arithm_op, file /home/pi/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp, line 1253
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
 what():  /home/pi/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:1253: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function arithm_op

I am not really able to understand what is going on. img1 and img2 are declared globally as Mat. 
This might be a simple issue, but I am still a novice. Please help me solve the issue.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first block of code, `img1` and `img2` are declared and contain two gray valid images (since you do `imread`). Note that these `img1` and `img2` are not global variables, but local. If you have global variables with the same names, the local ones shadow them.

In the second block, you define `img2` in the `else` and later do `img1 - img2`, but you don't show to us the value of `img1` (in this case, the global variable). The `img1` that is in the `if` is local to that `if` and is not visible in the `else`. Probably, you defined `cv::Mat img1` in the global scope but you didn't give it any value. This would cause an error in `img1-img2` because they are of different size (`img1` would be empty).

Update: Something like this should fix it.

```
// global scope
cv::Mat img1, img2, diffImage;

void yourFunction()
{
   ...
   img1 = cv::imread("/home/pi/test/Gray_2Image1.jpg", 0);
   img2 = cv::imread("/home/pi/test/Gray_2Image2.jpg", 0);
   diffImage = abs(img1-img2);
   ...
}
```

Update again: you can load the images in different if-else blocks as long as their declaration is visible.

This is **ok**:

```
// global scope
cv::Mat img1, img2, diffImage;

void yourFunction()
{
   ...
   if(condition)
   {
      img1 = cv::imread("/home/pi/test/Gray_2Image1.jpg", 0);
   }
   else
   {
      img2 = cv::imread("/home/pi/test/Gray_2Image2.jpg", 0);
   }
   ...
   diffImage = abs(img1-img2); // make sure img1 and img2 are loaded first
   ...
}
```

And this is **wrong**:

```
// global scope
cv::Mat img1, img2, diffImage;

void yourFunction()
{
   ...
   if(condition)
   {
      // wrong: you are creating a local variable that shadows the global one
      cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread("/home/pi/test/Gray_2Image1.jpg", 0);
   }
   ...
   diffImage = abs(img1-img2); // img1 is the global variable and not the local one in the previous if block!
   ...
}
```

Comment: Now I get the point. Is there a way to fix this problem? How can declare img1 and img2 in two different conditions and still use them without this error occurring. I have declared img1 and img2 as global variable and there are no local variables named img1 and img2.

Comment: I edited my answer to answer your comment. Note that you cannot declare variables in one scope and use them in another one where the first one is not visible. It it to say, you cannot declare a variable in the if block and use it in the else block, the declaration must be visible from the block where you use the variable. In my example, I used the global scope, so that you can use the variables in any if or else block. However, you should declare variables with the minimum scope that you need. In the example, if you don't need img1 or img2 outside yourFunction, they should be local better.

Comment: As you have said, it seems that the only way to do it is the way mentioned above which involves reading the two images at the same time in the same if or else.
Thank you very much for making me understand how it works.

Comment: Well, it is not exactly like that. You can load the images in any part of the code, but you must make sure that you do it in the visible cv::Mat and not a local one. Check out the two new examples.

Comment: The part where you say 'make sure img1 and img2 are loaded first' in the first code, where should they be loaded? Inside the 'if' and 'else' statements or outside them?

Comment: That depends on your code, the only important thing is that that happens before doing img1-img2. I guess that you have a loop with 2 iterations in which you load an image at each iteration. If that is the case, you should do something like: cv::Mat img1, img2, diffImg; for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){ if(i % 2 == 0) img1 = cv::imread(...); else img2 = cv::imread(...); } diffImg = abs(img1-img2);

Comment: I now completely understand what you want to convey. The above mentioned code would not work for me. The reason is that I am reading successive frames of a video and the execution line enters this function after each frame is read. So, I cannot use the for loop as above. With your help, i came up with this:

// global
cv::Mat img1, img2, diffImage;

gray=cvarrToMat(py);
if(img_num%2 == 1)
{
...
cv::Mat img2 = cv::imread(filename2, 0);
img1 = gray;
diffImage = abs(img1-img2);
}
else if (img_num%2 == 0)
{
...
cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread(filename1, 0);
img2 = gray;
diffImage = abs(img1-img2);
}

Comment: You can select my answer as the answer to your question then :)

Answer (score 0):

In the `else if` block - `img1` is not defined or empty - to give a better diagnosis, more code is required.

Also: why do you store `gray` to disk just in order to read it again?